# Rails render partial with collection—can't access collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections

I have a view calling this:

```
        <%= render 'health_safety/access_requests/access_request_user', collection: @access_request_users %>
```

And in `_access_request_user.html.erb` I'm *trying* to use the collection, e.g.

```
 <%= p access_request_user.inspect %>
```

And I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `access_request_user' for #<#<Class:0x007fc8f0160790>:0x007fc8ebf70100>
```

I'm absolutely stumped, tried heaps of things but nothing's working. If it makes a difference, `@access_request_users` is a bunch of `User` objects pulled from the database.

Comment: can you access it form terminal with Rails console ? >rails c

Comment: I'm not sure how to test it in the console, since I need render to work the magic that would turn @access_request_users into a new render with each one having an access_request_user variable.

Comment: Update: If I rename the partial `health_safety/users/_user` then i can simply call `render @access_request_users` and it finds the `_user` partial (because it's a collection of User I guess). But I'd prefer not to use the `health_safety/users` folder, I want to use that for other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining the render as a partial, and if this alone doesn't work try defining the name of the variable:

```
<%= render partial: 'health_safety/access_requests/access_request_user', collection: @access_request_users, as: :access_request_user %>
```

Comment: I danced around this statement for so long, but for some reason never actually tried this exact syntax. Thank you!